# Discord.py : line 343, in _run_event await coro(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: on_message_edit() takes 1 positional argument, but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm running a script, it shows me this error message:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message_edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Debashis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message_edit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

but my code is nothing more than:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(message):
  pass
```

I'll be working on the function later, but it gives me an error already (message intents are enabled). The other posts I found on this topic didn't help me at all. I don't know if that'll be helpful, but I'm not using `discord.Client`. I'm using `discord.ext.commands.Bot`.

Comment: [`on_message_edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message_edit#discord.on_message_edit) takes two arguements, not one. Can you edit your question to be a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```py
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
```

Where `before` is the previous version of the message and `after` is the current version ([documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#discord.on_message_edit)).

You might also think about using `on_raw_message_edit` as it's not relying on an internal cache ([documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#discord.on_raw_message_edit)).

```py
async def on_raw_message_edit(payload)
```